# Laravel number validation gte:5 and allow 0 too

Tags: laravel

I need number validation `gte:5` but allow `0` too

Laravel 8

Already tried `'price' => 'nullable|numeric|gte:5'`, but need to allow 0 when it's sent

Answer (score 1):

You must create a custom rule ([informations here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)).

Here :

```
Validator::extend('price_custom', function($attribute, $value){
    return $value === 0 || $value >= 5;
});
```

Then :

```
'price' => 'nullable|numeric|price_custom'
```